# Как пофиксить эффект гармошки со списком

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Есть кнопка, при клике происходит выпадение списка под этой кнопкой, происходит toggleSlide, но проблема в том, что во время выпадения или закрывания списка, я могу нажать на кнопку очень много раз и счетчик посчитает каждое нажатие и выполнит полный цикл открытия или скрытия списка.

```js
$('.faq-question').click(function() {
  $(this).next('.faq-answer').slideToggle();
  $(this).children('.fa').toggleClass('fa-plus-circle').toggleClass('fa-minus-circle');
 })
```

```css
.faq-answer{
display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="faq-item">
        <div class="faq-question">
            <p>Как пополнить свой склад?</p>
            <i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
        <p class="faq-answer">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusantium exercitationem aperiam adipisci distinctio autem laborum, quod enim aspernatur eligendi numquam architecto at earum, nihil repellendus est, quae nulla placeat cumque modi ea. Esse blanditiis dolorem cumque consectetur hic laboriosam minima nisi sit, delectus et at enim voluptas minus ratione quos!
        </p>
    </div>
```

Comment: stop() вам в помощь https://api.jquery.com/stop/

Comment: спасибо огромное

Answer (score 0):

```js
var busy = false;
$('.faq-question').click(function() {
  if (!busy) {
    console.log('slide start');
    busy = true;
    $(this).next('.faq-answer').slideToggle('slow', function() {
      busy = false;
      console.log('slide end')
    });
    $(this).children('.fa').toggleClass('fa-plus-circle').toggleClass('fa-minus-circle');
  }

})
```

```css
.faq-answer {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="faq-item">
  <div class="faq-question">
    <p>Как пополнить свой склад?</p>
    <i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </div>
  <p class="faq-answer">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusantium exercitationem aperiam adipisci distinctio autem laborum, quod enim aspernatur eligendi numquam architecto at earum, nihil repellendus est, quae nulla placeat cumque modi ea. Esse blanditiis
    dolorem cumque consectetur hic laboriosam minima nisi sit, delectus et at enim voluptas minus ratione quos!
  </p>
</div>
```